# Can you write a permutation function just as elegantly in C#?

Tags: c#, python, algorithm

I like this 6 line solution a lot and am trying to replicate it in C#. Basically, it permutes the elements of an array:

```
def permute(xs, pre=[]):
  if len(xs) == 0:
     yield pre
  for i, x in enumerate(xs):
     for y in permute(xs[:i] + xs[i+1:], pre + [x]):
        yield y
```

Comment: Lack of tuples and rather bulky list comprehensions (i.e. LINQ) will almost certainly make the C# code clumsier, but its definitely possible to translate the code above line for line into C#.

Comment: This is actually hard to read ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it probably isn't how I'd write it, but:

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> Permute<T>(this T[] xs, params T[] pre) {
    if (xs.Length == 0) yield return pre;
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.Length; i++) {
        foreach (T[] y in Permute(xs.Take(i).Union(xs.Skip(i+1)).ToArray(), pre.Union(new[] { xs[i] }).ToArray())) {
            yield return y;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Re your comment; I'm not *entirely* clear on the question; if you mean "why is this useful?" - among other things, there are a range of brute-force scenarios where you would want to try different permutations - for example, for small ordering problems like travelling sales person (that aren't big enough to warrant a more sophisticated solution), you might want to check whether it is best to go {base,A,B,C,base}, {base,A,C,B,base},{base,B,A,C,base}, etc.

If you mean "how would I use this method?" - untested, but something like:

```
int[] values = {1,2,3};
foreach(int[] perm in values.Permute()) {
   WriteArray(perm);
}

void WriteArray<T>(T[] values) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(T value in values) {
        sb.Append(value).Append(", ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

If you mean "how does it work?" - iterator blocks (`yield return`) are a complex subject in themselves - Jon has a free chapter (6) [in his book](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), though. The rest of the code is very much like your original question - just using LINQ to provide the moral equivalent of `+` (for arrays).

Comment: Well done! However, you're short of one line :) How would you write it? just curious, as I prefer readability over brevity too :)))

Comment: Well, it would involve less LINQ, and probably two methods (one for the public caller, one separate for recursion), and a re-used buffer. Or I'd look at the links in the other post ;-p

Comment: Marc, I like your solution "a lot",  However, I don't understand what it is doing... would you, or someone else, explain how to permutes over arrays and how it can be used? thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

C# has a yield keyword that I imagine works pretty much the same as what your python code is doing, so it shouldn't be too hard to get a mostly direct translation.

However this is a recursive solution, so for all it's brevity it's sub-optimal.  I don't personally understand all the math involved, but for good efficient mathematical permutations you want to use [factoradics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoradic).  This article should help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302371.aspx

[Update]:  The other answer brings up a good point: if you're just using permutations to do a shuffle there are still better options available.  Specifically, the [Knuth/Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) [shuffle](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html).

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot port it while maintaining the brevity, you can get pretty close.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
  {
    if (source == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return PermutationsImpl(source, new T[0]);
  }

  private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PermutationsImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> prefix)
  {
    if (source.Count() == 0)
      yield return prefix;

    foreach (var x in source)
      foreach (var permutation in PermutationsImpl(source.Except(new T[] { x }),
                                                   prefix.Union(new T[] { x }))))
        yield return permutation;
  }
}
```

Comment: The approach with Equals makes it hazardous for anything with either duplicates or nulls.

Comment: Regular permutations don't take duplicates (should be checked), but you are right about nulls.

Answer (score -6):

Not entirely to the point I must admit after some comments, but the code below can be used to generate a random permutation of a finite sequence. It's a variation of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle). The example uses a sequence of `int`'s but you can use any `Enumerable<T>` of course.

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 51);
var shuffledInts = ints.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());
```

You order by a random value (in this case a `Guid`) which essentially permutates your list. Whether [NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) is a good source of randomness is debatable, but it's an elegant and compact solution (albeit for another problem then the question was actually about).

Taken from [Jeff Atwood (Coding Horror)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001008.html).

Comment: How does this perform any permutations...?

Comment: +1 for a try... rwwilden would you do it with output as well?

Comment: If you order by a random value (a Guid in this case), you essentially permutate your list.

Comment: @rwwilden: permute != shuffle

Comment: shuffles are like a special case of a permutation, in that you can use permutations to shuffle accurately (if more slowly than with a specialized algorithm).  Even the wikipedia article above mentions Fisher-Yates as "based on the same principle".

Comment: Even so, ordering by a new guid is not the best idea, and while all shuffles are permutations, not all permutations are good shuffles.

Comment: After reading up on permutations I see that I have answered this one incorrect, sorry for that. However, the method described is a good way for generating random permutations of a finite set, although not as fast as possible (and the source of randomness is debatable). Updated my answer.