# Generating permutations of a set (most efficiently)

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, optimization, permutation

I would like to generate all permutations of a set (a collection), like so:

```
Collection: 1, 2, 3
Permutations: {1, 2, 3}
              {1, 3, 2}
              {2, 1, 3}
              {2, 3, 1}
              {3, 1, 2}
              {3, 2, 1}
```

This isn't a question of "how", in general, but more about how most efficiently.
Also, I wouldn't want to generate ALL permutations and return them, but only generating a single permutation, at a time, and continuing only if necessary (much like Iterators - which I've tried as well, but turned out to be less efficient).

I've tested many algorithms and approaches and came up with this code, which is most efficient of those I tried:

```
public static bool NextPermutation<T>(T[] elements) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // More efficient to have a variable instead of accessing a property
    var count = elements.Length;

    // Indicates whether this is the last lexicographic permutation
    var done = true;

    // Go through the array from last to first
    for (var i = count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var curr = elements[i];

        // Check if the current element is less than the one before it
        if (curr.CompareTo(elements[i - 1]) < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // An element bigger than the one before it has been found,
        // so this isn't the last lexicographic permutation.
        done = false;

        // Save the previous (bigger) element in a variable for more efficiency.
        var prev = elements[i - 1];

        // Have a variable to hold the index of the element to swap
        // with the previous element (the to-swap element would be
        // the smallest element that comes after the previous element
        // and is bigger than the previous element), initializing it
        // as the current index of the current item (curr).
        var currIndex = i;

        // Go through the array from the element after the current one to last
        for (var j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
        {
            // Save into variable for more efficiency
            var tmp = elements[j];

            // Check if tmp suits the "next swap" conditions:
            // Smallest, but bigger than the "prev" element
            if (tmp.CompareTo(curr) < 0 && tmp.CompareTo(prev) > 0)
            {
                curr = tmp;
                currIndex = j;
            }
        }

        // Swap the "prev" with the new "curr" (the swap-with element)
        elements[currIndex] = prev;
        elements[i - 1] = curr;

        // Reverse the order of the tail, in order to reset it's lexicographic order
        for (var j = count - 1; j > i; j--, i++)
        {
            var tmp = elements[j];
            elements[j] = elements[i];
            elements[i] = tmp;
        }

        // Break since we have got the next permutation
        // The reason to have all the logic inside the loop is
        // to prevent the need of an extra variable indicating "i" when
        // the next needed swap is found (moving "i" outside the loop is a
        // bad practice, and isn't very readable, so I preferred not doing
        // that as well).
        break;
    }

    // Return whether this has been the last lexicographic permutation.
    return done;
}
```

It's usage would be sending an array of elements, and getting back a boolean indicating whether this was the last lexicographical permutation or not, as well as having the array altered to the next permutation.

Usage example:

```
var arr = new[] {1, 2, 3};

PrintArray(arr);

while (!NextPermutation(arr))
{
    PrintArray(arr);
}
```

The thing is that I'm not happy with the speed of the code.

Iterating over all permutations of an array of size 11 takes about 4 seconds.
Although it could be considered impressive, since the amount of possible permutations of a set of size 11 is `11!` which is nearly 40 million.

Logically, with an array of size 12 it will take about 12 times more time, since `12!` is `11! * 12`, and with an array of size 13 it will take about 13 times more time than the time it took with size 12, and so on.

So you can easily understand how with an array of size 12 and more, it really takes a very long time to go through all permutations.

And I have a strong hunch that I can somehow cut that time by a lot (without switching to a language other than C# - because compiler optimization really does optimize pretty nicely, and I doubt I could optimize as good, manually, in Assembly).

Does anyone know any other way to get that done faster?
Do you have any idea as to how to make the current algorithm faster?

Note that I don't want to use an external library or service in order to do that - I want to have the code itself and I want it to be as efficient as humanly possible.

Comment: Generating **all** permutations cannot be done faster than the number of permutations.

Comment: I'm confused by this line: "but only generating a single permutation, at a time, and continuing only if necessary". What is your goal?

Comment: One other thing to try is to write something that "visits" each permutation, calling a user-specified function with each in turn. That way you could write a recursive function to generate the permutations. It may or may not be faster: the "current position" is maintained on the stack rather than found each time by the check-and-continue at the start of your loop. Then again, that check doesn't take many steps on average to find the point it needs to work from, so you won't find any order-of-magnitude improvement this way.

Comment: Is the set to contain only unique elements?

Comment: If you want to make your **implementation** faster, then I might be able to help you. I guess that a large amount of time is spent on printing the result.

Comment: Btw, since the thing you're doing is inherently `O(n!)`-ish, there will always be a quite small number for which you're saying, "it takes a few seconds to do M, but M+1 will take M+1 times as long". Even if you could speed your code up a million times, you'd only get from 12 to 17. Would that make you a million times happier?

Comment: @nhahtdh That is obvious, but I still feel the current algorithm can be improved.

Comment: @EmilVikström This means that if the outside code wants to iterate over the permutations, and decides to stop at a certain point, I wouldn't have created unnecessary permutations.

Comment: @SteveJessop I've tried a few recursive approaches as well, but none was found as good as the one I'm currently using.

Comment: @Lieven You can assume that it does.

Comment: @nhahtdh The speed tests were made with only iterating over the permutations - not print or aything.

Comment: @SteveJessop Very good point - but yes, it would make be a million times happier :)

Comment: I don't know C# or how it optimizes, but maybe you should somehow figure out whether the JIT has managed to remove all the bounds-checking from those array accesses. Logically none of the indexes can possibly exceed the array bounds. If the compiler/runtime hasn't figured that out, you might be able to shave a bit if you can help it. That could be by massaging this code, or by using pointers.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Are you sure you're not I/O bound and spending most of the time in `PrintArray()`?

Comment: @SteveJessop Nice suggestion, but I can't expect the improvement will be more than by 1%, which isn't quiet what I'm looking for.

Comment: "Compress" the data to byte or half-byte (nibble) - if possible in C#. This is the only optimization I can think of. Your algorithm probably is the same as Wikipedia's. Have you compare your code against C++ next_permutation, just to see how good your code is?

Comment: @Blastfurnace The PrintArray is just an example of how to use it. When I'm testing speeds I do not print the array or do anything with it - just iterating over permutations.

Comment: @nhahtdh What do you mean by "compressing the data"? Please elaborate.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Agreed, it might not be worth the time spent figuring out how to check the actual native code generated. Especially if it turns out that the JIT *is* smart enough, and therefore you get no speed-up at all!

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Instead of operating on 4 bytes, operate on 1 byte, or half a byte. I'm not sure if this will be any faster, though. Esp. on such small data. It works very well on a large array in C, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh No, it wouldn't be any faster, and I wouldn't want to limit the out-side code to use bytes - that is why the whole method is generic. I'm only using integers for speed-tests, but the implementation works for every type that implements IComparable - and the comparing time isn't really up to me.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: I don't think it's possible to significantly improve your implementation then.

Comment: @nhahtdh I agree, but maybe improve the algorithm itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319049/generating-permutations-using-linq

Comment: @DaveBish How does that help me? This generates combinations, not permutations.

Comment: I'd like to point out this algo do not handle permutation(n,k) when k < n

Comment: @SimpleVar, You seem to want the result in lexicographical order while it is not mentioned clearly in your question. Is that a must or not? If it is, then you should clearly state it into your question because it add a constraint on the algorithm which could clearly affect the performance.

Comment: @SimpleVar, Also, if you were looking for the fastest algorithm that you can stop, I'm pretty sure you will never find something that beat my answer. But it is not in lexicographical order.

Comment: @EricOuellet It does looks promising. Initially I think I was going after lexicographic ordering, but quickly it was revealed that there are just more interesting things to do for non-ordered perms. So the thread is about both lex and non-lex, racing separately, I guess. But I assure you I stopped looking ;)

Comment: @SimpleVar, I'm not sure but I guess that there couln't be a solution which is the fastest and also being lexicograghic. That is due to the fact that the fastest implies only one swap of only 2 items while lexicographic implies more than one swap (some times) if there is more than 2 items. I do not say it is impossible but I can't see how :-) !

Comment: @EricOuellet Beats me, them maths are full of surprises. Maybe one day a guy will find a way to do it (lexicographic) iteratively in `n! + n log (n!)` or something. My logic agrees with you, but my self esteem doesn't :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Update 2018-05-28:
>
> - A new multithreaded version (lot faster) is available below as another answer.
> - Also an article about permutation: [Permutations: Fast implementations and a new indexing algorithm allowing multithreading](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250925/Permutations-Fast-implementations-and-a-new-indexi)

A little bit too late...

According to recent tests (updated 2018-05-22)

- Fastest is mine BUT not in lexicographic order
- For fastest lexicographic order, Sani Singh Huttunen solution seems to be the way to go.

Performance test results for 10 items (10!) in release on my machine (millisecs):

- Ouellet : 29
- SimpleVar: 95
- Erez Robinson : 156
- Sani Singh Huttunen : 37
- Pengyang : 45047

Performance test results for 13 items (13!) in release on my machine (seconds):

- Ouellet : 48.437
- SimpleVar: 159.869
- Erez Robinson : 327.781
- Sani Singh Huttunen : 64.839

---

Advantages of my solution:

- Heap's algorithm (Single swap per permutation)
- No multiplication (like some implementations seen on the web)
- Inlined swap
- Generic
- No unsafe code
- In place (very low memory usage)
- No modulo (only first bit compare)

My implementation of [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfPermutations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// EO: 2016-04-14
    /// Generator of all permutations of an array of anything.
    /// Base on Heap's Algorithm. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm#cite_note-3
    /// </summary>
    public static class Permutations
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Heap's algorithm to find all pmermutations. Non recursive, more efficient.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="items">Items to permute in each possible ways</param>
        /// <param name="funcExecuteAndTellIfShouldStop"></param>
        /// <returns>Return true if cancelled</returns> 
        public static bool ForAllPermutation<T>(T[] items, Func<T[], bool> funcExecuteAndTellIfShouldStop)
        {
            int countOfItem = items.Length;

            if (countOfItem <= 1)
            {
                return funcExecuteAndTellIfShouldStop(items);
            }

            var indexes = new int[countOfItem];
            
            // Unecessary. Thanks to NetManage for the advise
            // for (int i = 0; i < countOfItem; i++)
            // {
            //     indexes[i] = 0;
            // }

            if (funcExecuteAndTellIfShouldStop(items))
            {
                return true;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < countOfItem;)
            {
                if (indexes[i] < i)
                { // On the web there is an implementation with a multiplication which should be less efficient.
                    if ((i & 1) == 1) // if (i % 2 == 1)  ... more efficient ??? At least the same.
                    {
                        Swap(ref items[i], ref items[indexes[i]]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Swap(ref items[i], ref items[0]);
                    }

                    if (funcExecuteAndTellIfShouldStop(items))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    indexes[i]++;
                    i = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    indexes[i++] = 0;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is to show a linq way but is far less efficient
        /// From: StackOverflow user: Pengyang : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="list"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length)
        {
            if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });

            return GetPermutations(list, length - 1)
                .SelectMany(t => list.Where(e => !t.Contains(e)),
                    (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Swap 2 elements of same type
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="a"></param>
        /// <param name="b"></param>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
        {
            T temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Func to show how to call. It does a little test for an array of 4 items.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Test()
        {
            ForAllPermutation("123".ToCharArray(), (vals) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", vals));
                return false;
            });

            int[] values = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 4 };

            Console.WriteLine("Ouellet heap's algorithm implementation");
            ForAllPermutation(values, (vals) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", vals));
                return false;
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Linq algorithm");
            foreach (var v in GetPermutations(values, values.Length))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", v));
            }

            // Performance Heap's against Linq version : huge differences
            int count = 0;

            values = new int[10];
            for (int n = 0; n < values.Length; n++)
            {
                values[n] = n;
            }

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            ForAllPermutation(values, (vals) =>
            {
                foreach (var v in vals)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                return false;
            });

            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Ouellet heap's algorithm implementation {count} items in {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisecs");

            count = 0;
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();

            foreach (var vals in GetPermutations(values, values.Length))
            {
                foreach (var v in vals)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Linq {count} items in {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisecs");
        }
    }
}
```

An this is my test code:

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {

                int[] values = new int[12];
                for (int n = 0; n < values.Length; n++)
                {
                    values[n] = n;
                }

                // Eric Ouellet Algorithm
                int count = 0;
                var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Reset();
                stopwatch.Start();
                Permutations.ForAllPermutation(values, (vals) =>
                {
                    foreach (var v in vals)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"This {count} items in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisecs");

                // Simple Plan Algorithm
                count = 0;
                stopwatch.Reset();
                stopwatch.Start();
                PermutationsSimpleVar permutations2 = new PermutationsSimpleVar();
                permutations2.Permutate(1, values.Length, (int[] vals) =>
                {
                    foreach (var v in vals)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                });
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Simple Plan {count} items in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisecs");

                // ErezRobinson Algorithm
                count = 0;
                stopwatch.Reset();
                stopwatch.Start();
                foreach(var vals in PermutationsErezRobinson.QuickPerm(values))
                {
                    foreach (var v in vals)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                };
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Erez Robinson {count} items in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisecs");
            });
```

Usage examples:

```
ForAllPermutation("123".ToCharArray(), (vals) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", vals));
        return false;
    });

int[] values = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 4 };
ForAllPermutation(values, (vals) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", vals));
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Trusting your benchmark, I've marked this as the answer. Looks really sweet!

Comment: Thanks! I just implemented what I found in Wikipedia.

Comment: Of course Heap's is faster than most (all?) other algorithms. But it "breaks" the original requirement of "lexicographical order".

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen, I agree it is a not in lexicographical order but if I remember well, I think it was not a requirement of the original question... It depends on your needs...

Comment: Question still says: "It's usage would be sending an array of elements, and getting back a boolean indicating whether this was the last lexicographical permutation or not...". This indicates that lexicographical order is a requirement.

Comment: And also as OP (SimpleVar) wrote in another comment: "This is about 3 times slower than my current implementation, and doesn't iterate in lexicographic order as well."

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen, You are actually right but the question could have been updated since I answered. I cannot comment on things that could have been or not. It is also possible that my answer was not exactly as it should be. What do you expect? Do yo want me to remove my answer? I do not plan to remove it. But I added clarification at first line in order to help peoples make a better choice according to their needs.

Comment: @EricOuellet: No. Your answer should stand. OP's requirements have changed since first asked and today your answer is probably the most relevant. I just wanted to point out that originally the requirements where lexicographical order but OP himself changed that later on. (P.S. I already upvoted your answer).

Comment: can this be modified to include permutations without repetitions ?

Comment: I do not understand your question? Permutation always give you a unique set (arrangement) of all values. Can you explain a little bit more what you are looking for?

Comment: Note that in C# a new array is guaranteed to be initialized to the default of it's type, so `var indexes = new int[countOfItem];` creates `indexes` with all elements as `0` (`default(int)`) and you don't need to set them. PS Typo in summary: pmer

Comment: Consider (in today's C#) you could replace your first two `if`s with `if ((funcExecuteAndTellIfShouldStop(items) is var firstStopFlag) || countOfItem <= 1)
            return firstStopFlag;`

Comment: If I have a list of 1..25, is there a way to say permutate my list but only take first 10 values of each permutation...and the length of the generation is = generating permutation of list size 10?  Or would I need to do the entire permutation of 25 items and then post process the results and only use first 10 digits of each result?

Comment: @Terry, I'm not sure to understand you properly. You do not have to process the entire set of permutation (which in your case would be immensely huge => 25! ). You can use any permutation result whenever you want. Remember that my algorithm has results unsorted (that's why it is the fastest). So you need to consider that the first 10 values could be any of the 25 values (not true but kind of). Also you can try to understand the code (not very difficult), or read: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250925/Permutations-Fast-implementations-and-a-new-indexi

Answer (score 39):

This might be what you're looking for.

```
    private static bool NextPermutation(int[] numList)
    {
        /*
         Knuths
         1. Find the largest index j such that a[j] < a[j + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
         2. Find the largest index l such that a[j] < a[l]. Since j + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies j < l.
         3. Swap a[j] with a[l].
         4. Reverse the sequence from a[j + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

         */
        var largestIndex = -1;
        for (var i = numList.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (numList[i] < numList[i + 1]) {
                largestIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (largestIndex < 0) return false;

        var largestIndex2 = -1;
        for (var i = numList.Length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (numList[largestIndex] < numList[i]) {
                largestIndex2 = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        var tmp = numList[largestIndex];
        numList[largestIndex] = numList[largestIndex2];
        numList[largestIndex2] = tmp;

        for (int i = largestIndex + 1, j = numList.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            tmp = numList[i];
            numList[i] = numList[j];
            numList[j] = tmp;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is a tiny bit faster than my implementation, thank you very much! I still expect an improvement to be a lot more significant - which would probably mean an alteration in the algorithm itself. +1 for valid answer, though!

Comment: Testing for an array of size 12 shows that my implementation took 46 seconds, while yours took 43, so even though you beat me by 3 seconds, I'm looking for a way to half the time, at the very least.

Comment: 3 seconds is an eternity on SO... ;) One way to improve significantly would be to parallelize the algorithm. But that is not always applicable. But have a look here: http://scidok.sulb.uni-saarland.de/volltexte/2005/397/pdf/sfb124-94-02.pdf

Comment: I agree with Sani.  You should definitely go with taking advantage with muliple cores - much more efficient. Take a look at the TPL in .NET 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: I came up with a really great algorithm, that although doesn't go through the permutations in a lexicographic order, it should be easily altered to do so (since it is nearly-lexicographic at the moment - probably just a tiny bug) - and it iterates through all permutations of a set of size 12 and performs an action on each (testing with empty action) - only 8.14 seconds! Size 13 takes 1.5min, and there are a few further adjustments to make to the code, so I'm happy with it :)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I think I will post an article somewhere of my work. For now, I'm still working on it, coming up with more and more micro-adjustments, testing out new things, etc. The general idea is to only make exactly n! swaps, and as few extra logic as possible.

Comment: I've decided to accept your answer since it was the best of all answers here and made me have a breakthrough. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you find a better algorithm?

Comment: @YoryeNathan [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) algorithm is n! swaps

Comment: @colinfang Any naive algorithm can perform in `n!` swaps. The thing is that you also need to find which elements to swap. I challenge you to do that in `O(n!)` ;)

Comment: Its funny.. I remember working on this great code, performing better than any algorithm I've managed to come across by far, and I even remember the way it looks (line-lengths-structure-wise), but it seems that I can't find it. It's deeply buried somewhere in my projects folder, in a project with a totally unsuitable name that was initially created for something completely different. Fun. Funny.

Comment: @YoryeNathan and you owe the readers "I think I will post an article somewhere of my work."

Comment: @colinfang A penny for my thoughts

Comment: @colinfang I'm now performing a content-search over my whole drive, since I couldn't find it in the projects folder. Back soon with results.

Comment: @colinfang So, I actually found it (yay! :D) but it isn't lexicographic. However, it does perform nicely. About 1.5sec for 11 elements. Not sure if it's worth an article or even a post, since it's nothing revolutionary - just tons of optimizations.

Comment: @YoryeNathan so your non-lexicographic algorithm is about 2.2 seconds faster than Knuths? I would still like to see it.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen The only thing that stops me from publishing is the feeling that with some strange and awesome math, a new algorithm can be 1000% faster. But I just can't come up with it. By the way, 1.5sec is worse speed. It's sometimes 1.3 ;)

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Still would like to see it. Might be good to get some outside insight... ;)

Comment: @YoryeNathan, Code, or it didn't happen.

Comment: This the only question I've ever asked that has become this popular, and after re-reading the comments, I have decided that I should post my code that I had at the time, since I'm no longer really ever thinking about this. So if anyone was waiting - sorry, and get a life. I'll search again for that deeply buried solution and post it asap.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen added my code as an answer! Let me know how you like it ;p

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen, Hey! Just to tell you that I post a new answer where I'm using your code (and more) that I multi-threaded. Results are 4x faster on my machine. In order to go faster, I had to find a way to call an algorithm from anywhere in the sequence of permutation. I did one which is quite slow but I called only once per thread as first call then I call your algorithm. We should be able to get to best answer altogether ;-) !!!

Answer (score 12):

Well, if you can handle it in C and then translate to your language of choice, you can't really go much faster than this, because the time will be dominated by `print`:

```
void perm(char* s, int n, int i){
  if (i >= n-1) print(s);
  else {
    perm(s, n, i+1);
    for (int j = i+1; j<n; j++){
      swap(s[i], s[j]);
      perm(s, n, i+1);
      swap(s[i], s[j]);
    }
  }
}

perm("ABC", 3, 0);
```

Comment: That was one of the first algorithms I came up with and tried, but it isn't the fastest. My current implementation is faster.

Comment: @Yorye: Well, as I said, nearly all the time is in print. If you just comment out the print, you will see how much time the algorithm itself takes. In C#, where you are encouraged to make collection classes, iterators, and do all kinds of memory allocation, any good algorithm can be made slow as molasses.

Comment: The speed testing is without printing - only going through the permutations. The algorithm itself is slower than mine. I only use integers and arrays in my implementation.

Comment: @Yorye: OK, two swaps takes maybe 8 instructions. A function call, entry, and return takes maybe 10 at most. The inner couple of loops are dominant, so you're talking maybe 20 instructions per permutation. If you're beating that, that's pretty clever.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure I've got something. I'm working on it :)

Comment: Great answer. Translated that without issue into C# (working on ref int[]).

Comment: This is the best algorithm, small, clean, no mutexes, great one, thanks!

Comment: This code is hard to understand. It makes 0 sense to be terse with variable names in this instance.

Comment: Is there a way to make this return combinations? If so, does it have to create permutations first?

Answer (score 9):

Update 2018-05-28, a new version, the fastest ... (multi-threaded)

[image]

```
                            Time taken for fastest algorithms
```

Need: Sani Singh Huttunen (fastest lexico) solution and my new OuelletLexico3 which support indexing

Indexing has 2 main advantages:

- allows to get anyone permutation directly
- allows multi-threading (derived from the first advantage)

Article: [Permutations: Fast implementations and a new indexing algorithm allowing multithreading](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250925/Permutations-Fast-implementations-and-a-new-indexi)

On my machine (6 hyperthread cores : 12 threads) Xeon E5-1660 0 @ 3.30Ghz, tests algorithms running with empty stuff to do for 13! items (time in millisecs):

- 53071: Ouellet (implementation of Heap)
- 65366: Sani Singh Huttunen (Fastest lexico)
- 11377: Mix OuelletLexico3 - Sani Singh Huttunen

A side note: using shares properties/variables between threads for permutation action will strongly impact performance if their usage is modification (read / write). Doing so will generate "[false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads)" between threads. You will not get expected performance. I got this behavior while testing. My experience showed problems when I try to increase the global variable for the total count of permutation.

Usage:

```
PermutationMixOuelletSaniSinghHuttunen.ExecuteForEachPermutationMT(
  new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
  p => 
    { 
      Console.WriteLine($"Values: {p[0]}, {p[1]}, p[2]}, {p[3]}"); 
    });
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfPermutations
{
    public class Factorial
    {
        // ************************************************************************
        protected static long[] FactorialTable = new long[21];

        // ************************************************************************
        static Factorial()
        {
            FactorialTable[0] = 1; // To prevent divide by 0
            long f = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                f = f * i;
                FactorialTable[i] = f;
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static long GetFactorial(int val) // a long can only support up to 20!
        {
            if (val > 20)
            {
                throw new OverflowException($"{nameof(Factorial)} only support a factorial value <= 20");
            }

            return FactorialTable[val];
        }

        // ************************************************************************

    }
}


namespace WpfPermutations
{
    public class PermutationSaniSinghHuttunen
    {
        public static bool NextPermutation(int[] numList)
        {
            /*
             Knuths
             1. Find the largest index j such that a[j] < a[j + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
             2. Find the largest index l such that a[j] < a[l]. Since j + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies j < l.
             3. Swap a[j] with a[l].
             4. Reverse the sequence from a[j + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

             */
            var largestIndex = -1;
            for (var i = numList.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (numList[i] < numList[i + 1])
                {
                    largestIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (largestIndex < 0) return false;

            var largestIndex2 = -1;
            for (var i = numList.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (numList[largestIndex] < numList[i])
                {
                    largestIndex2 = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            var tmp = numList[largestIndex];
            numList[largestIndex] = numList[largestIndex2];
            numList[largestIndex2] = tmp;

            for (int i = largestIndex + 1, j = numList.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            {
                tmp = numList[i];
                numList[i] = numList[j];
                numList[j] = tmp;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}


using System;

namespace WpfPermutations
{
    public class PermutationOuelletLexico3<T> // Enable indexing 
    {
        // ************************************************************************
        private T[] _sortedValues;

        private bool[] _valueUsed;

        public readonly long MaxIndex; // long to support 20! or less 

        // ************************************************************************
        public PermutationOuelletLexico3(T[] sortedValues)
        {
            _sortedValues = sortedValues;
            Result = new T[_sortedValues.Length];
            _valueUsed = new bool[_sortedValues.Length];

            MaxIndex = Factorial.GetFactorial(_sortedValues.Length);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public T[] Result { get; private set; }

        // ************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Sort Index is 0 based and should be less than MaxIndex. Otherwise you get an exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sortIndex"></param>
        /// <param name="result">Value is not used as inpu, only as output. Re-use buffer in order to save memory</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void GetSortedValuesFor(long sortIndex)
        {
            int size = _sortedValues.Length;

            if (sortIndex < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sortIndex should greater or equal to 0.");
            }

            if (sortIndex >= MaxIndex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sortIndex should less than factorial(the lenght of items)");
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < _valueUsed.Length; n++)
            {
                _valueUsed[n] = false;
            }

            long factorielLower = MaxIndex;

            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            {
                long factorielBigger = factorielLower;
                factorielLower = Factorial.GetFactorial(size - index - 1);  //  factorielBigger / inverseIndex;

                int resultItemIndex = (int)(sortIndex % factorielBigger / factorielLower);

                int correctedResultItemIndex = 0;
                for(;;)
                {
                    if (! _valueUsed[correctedResultItemIndex])
                    {
                        resultItemIndex--;
                        if (resultItemIndex < 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    correctedResultItemIndex++;
                }

                Result[index] = _sortedValues[correctedResultItemIndex];
                _valueUsed[correctedResultItemIndex] = true;
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfPermutations
{
    public class PermutationMixOuelletSaniSinghHuttunen
    {
        // ************************************************************************
        private long _indexFirst;
        private long _indexLastExclusive;
        private int[] _sortedValues;

        // ************************************************************************
        public PermutationMixOuelletSaniSinghHuttunen(int[] sortedValues, long indexFirst = -1, long indexLastExclusive = -1)
        {
            if (indexFirst == -1)
            {
                indexFirst = 0;
            }

            if (indexLastExclusive == -1)
            {
                indexLastExclusive = Factorial.GetFactorial(sortedValues.Length);
            }

            if (indexFirst >= indexLastExclusive)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(indexFirst)} should be less than {nameof(indexLastExclusive)}");
            }

            _indexFirst = indexFirst;
            _indexLastExclusive = indexLastExclusive;
            _sortedValues = sortedValues;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public void ExecuteForEachPermutation(Action<int[]> action)
        {
            //          Console.WriteLine($"Thread {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} started: {_indexFirst} {_indexLastExclusive}");

            long index = _indexFirst;

            PermutationOuelletLexico3<int> permutationOuellet = new PermutationOuelletLexico3<int>(_sortedValues);

            permutationOuellet.GetSortedValuesFor(index);
            action(permutationOuellet.Result);
            index++;

            int[] values = permutationOuellet.Result;
            while (index < _indexLastExclusive)
            {
                PermutationSaniSinghHuttunen.NextPermutation(values);
                action(values);
                index++;
            }

            //          Console.WriteLine($"Thread {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} ended: {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_ffffff")}");
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public static void ExecuteForEachPermutationMT(int[] sortedValues, Action<int[]> action)
        {
            int coreCount = Environment.ProcessorCount; // Hyper treading are taken into account (ex: on a 4 cores hyperthreaded = 8)
            long itemsFactorial = Factorial.GetFactorial(sortedValues.Length);
            long partCount = (long)Math.Ceiling((double)itemsFactorial / (double)coreCount);
            long startIndex = 0;

            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int coreIndex = 0; coreIndex < coreCount; coreIndex++)
            {
                long stopIndex = Math.Min(startIndex + partCount, itemsFactorial);

                PermutationMixOuelletSaniSinghHuttunen mix = new PermutationMixOuelletSaniSinghHuttunen(sortedValues, startIndex, stopIndex);
                Task task = Task.Run(() => mix.ExecuteForEachPermutation(action));
                tasks.Add(task);

                if (stopIndex == itemsFactorial)
                {
                    break;
                }

                startIndex = startIndex + partCount;
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        // ************************************************************************


    }
}
```

Comment: Boom, baby. Boom! Some would say multi-threading is cheating.. but not me :P Generating permutations is a great thing to parallelize, and you can really only go so far without threading

Comment: 100% agree with you! :-)... In many cases a faster MT solution would be preferred to a slower ST one. Just to let you, I would have need it that code a year or two ago.

Comment: Impressive implementation indeed! Wish I could +100 this!

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen, Wow! Thank you very much! I wouldn't achieve that performance without your code. It's really the combination of both... +100 to you also :-) !

Answer (score 8):

The fastest permutation algorithm that i know of is the QuickPerm algorithm.
Here is the implementation, it uses yield return so you can iterate one at a time like required.

**Code:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> QuickPerm<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set)
    {
        int N = set.Count();
        int[] a = new int[N];
        int[] p = new int[N];

        var yieldRet = new T[N];

        List<T> list = new List<T>(set);

        int i, j, tmp; // Upper Index i; Lower Index j

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            // initialize arrays; a[N] can be any type
            a[i] = i + 1; // a[i] value is not revealed and can be arbitrary
            p[i] = 0; // p[i] == i controls iteration and index boundaries for i
        }
        yield return list;
        //display(a, 0, 0);   // remove comment to display array a[]
        i = 1; // setup first swap points to be 1 and 0 respectively (i & j)
        while (i < N)
        {
            if (p[i] < i)
            {
                j = i%2*p[i]; // IF i is odd then j = p[i] otherwise j = 0
                tmp = a[j]; // swap(a[j], a[i])
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = tmp;

                //MAIN!

                for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
                {
                    yieldRet[x] = list[a[x]-1];
                }
                yield return yieldRet;
                //display(a, j, i); // remove comment to display target array a[]

                // MAIN!

                p[i]++; // increase index "weight" for i by one
                i = 1; // reset index i to 1 (assumed)
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise p[i] == i
                p[i] = 0; // reset p[i] to zero
                i++; // set new index value for i (increase by one)
            } // if (p[i] < i)
        } // while(i < N)
    }
```

Comment: This is about 3 times slower than my current implementation, and doesn't iterate in lexicographic order as well.

Comment: I haven't checked the lexographical order, but in my computer QuickPerm took 11 seconds for 11 items and your algo took 15 seconds. Anyhow, I wish you best of luck.

Comment: @ErezRobinson: This takes about 7 seconds compared to 1.7 seconds of my implementation of Knuths algorithm with 11 elements on my computer so your algorithm is over 4 times slower.

Comment: Yes, Knuth is faster :) however, still Yorye is still slow for me, maybe I'm checking it wrong.

Comment: @ErezRobinson My implementation is 3.8~3.9 seconds on my computer (which isn't a great one), and yours is 13 seconds. Sani's is 3.7~3.8 for me.

Comment: @ErezRobinson By the way, turns out my implementation is actually Knuth-style.

Comment: For a list of 12 items (39,916,800 permutations) this code takes ~ 1 min 51 seconds vs. ~ 1 min 13 seconds for the code I posted.

Comment: Thanks, Erez, this is very useful extension method that will work on any IEnumerable Type.

Comment: This code is hard to understand. It makes 0 sense to be terse with variable names in this instance.

Comment: Be careful if you use the returned value in some lazy evaluations like LINQ. The returned value is almost always the same object. You will need to copy the value yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is the fastest implementation I ended up with:**

```
public class Permutations
{
    private readonly Mutex _mutex = new Mutex();

    private Action<int[]> _action;
    private Action<IntPtr> _actionUnsafe;
    private unsafe int* _arr;
    private IntPtr _arrIntPtr;
    private unsafe int* _last;
    private unsafe int* _lastPrev;
    private unsafe int* _lastPrevPrev;

    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public bool IsRunning()
    {
        return this._mutex.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed;
    }

    public bool Permutate(int start, int count, Action<int[]> action, bool async = false)
    {
        return this.Permutate(start, count, action, null, async);
    }

    public bool Permutate(int start, int count, Action<IntPtr> actionUnsafe, bool async = false)
    {
        return this.Permutate(start, count, null, actionUnsafe, async);
    }

    private unsafe bool Permutate(int start, int count, Action<int[]> action, Action<IntPtr> actionUnsafe, bool async = false)
    {
        if (!this._mutex.WaitOne(0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var x = (Action)(() =>
                             {
                                 this._actionUnsafe = actionUnsafe;
                                 this._action = action;

                                 this.Size = count;

                                 this._arr = (int*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count * sizeof(int));
                                 this._arrIntPtr = new IntPtr(this._arr);

                                 for (var i = 0; i < count - 3; i++)
                                 {
                                     this._arr[i] = start + i;
                                 }

                                 this._last = this._arr + count - 1;
                                 this._lastPrev = this._last - 1;
                                 this._lastPrevPrev = this._lastPrev - 1;

                                 *this._last = count - 1;
                                 *this._lastPrev = count - 2;
                                 *this._lastPrevPrev = count - 3;

                                 this.Permutate(count, this._arr);
                             });

        if (!async)
        {
            x();
        }
        else
        {
            new Thread(() => x()).Start();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private unsafe void Permutate(int size, int* start)
    {
        if (size == 3)
        {
            this.DoAction();
            Swap(this._last, this._lastPrev);
            this.DoAction();
            Swap(this._last, this._lastPrevPrev);
            this.DoAction();
            Swap(this._last, this._lastPrev);
            this.DoAction();
            Swap(this._last, this._lastPrevPrev);
            this.DoAction();
            Swap(this._last, this._lastPrev);
            this.DoAction();

            return;
        }

        var sizeDec = size - 1;
        var startNext = start + 1;
        var usedStarters = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < sizeDec; i++)
        {
            this.Permutate(sizeDec, startNext);

            usedStarters |= 1 << *start;

            for (var j = startNext; j <= this._last; j++)
            {
                var mask = 1 << *j;

                if ((usedStarters & mask) != mask)
                {
                    Swap(start, j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        this.Permutate(sizeDec, startNext);

        if (size == this.Size)
        {
            this._mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private unsafe void DoAction()
    {
        if (this._action == null)
        {
            if (this._actionUnsafe != null)
            {
                this._actionUnsafe(this._arrIntPtr);
            }

            return;
        }

        var result = new int[this.Size];

        fixed (int* pt = result)
        {
            var limit = pt + this.Size;
            var resultPtr = pt;
            var arrayPtr = this._arr;

            while (resultPtr < limit)
            {
                *resultPtr = *arrayPtr;
                resultPtr++;
                arrayPtr++;
            }
        }

        this._action(result);
    }

    private static unsafe void Swap(int* a, int* b)
    {
        var tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
    }
}
```

**Usage and testing performance:**

```
var perms = new Permutations();

var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

perms.Permutate(0,
                11,
                (Action<int[]>)null); // Comment this line and...
                //PrintArr); // Uncomment this line, to print permutations

sw1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw1.Elapsed);
```

**Printing method:**

```
private static void PrintArr(int[] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arr));
}
```

**Going deeper:**

I did not even think about this for a very long time, so I can only explain my code so much, but here's the general idea:

1. Permutations aren't lexicographic - this allows me to practically perform less operations between permutations.
2. The implementation is recursive, and when the "view" size is 3, it skips the complex logic and just performs 6 swaps to get the 6 permutations (or sub-permutations, if you will).
3. Because the permutations aren't in a lexicographic order, how can I decide which element to bring to the start of the current "view" (sub permutation)? I keep record of elements that were already used as "starters" in the current sub-permutation recursive call and simply search linearly for one that wasn't used in the tail of my array.
4. The implementation is for integers only, so to permute over a generic collection of elements you simply use the Permutations class to permute indices instead of your actual collection.
5. The Mutex is there just to ensure things don't get screwed when the execution is asynchronous (notice that you can pass an UnsafeAction parameter that will in turn get a pointer to the permuted array. You must not change the order of elements in that array (pointer)! If you want to, you should copy the array to a tmp array or just use the safe action parameter which takes care of that for you - the passed array is already a copy).

**Note:**

I have no idea how good this implementation really is - I haven't touched it in so long.
Test and compare to other implementations on your own, and let me know if you have any feedback!

Enjoy.

Comment: @Lu4 What's awful about it? The more optimizations, the less beautiful the code - but it runs lightning fast.

Comment: Your original implementation (provided in your question) is the best solution here. It's clean and fast code and generates sorted permutation. I'd never use this marked as answer actually...

Comment: P.S. I'm actually studying your original solution, I had the same intuitions you had but I did not manage to code a general solution. Well done.

Comment: @sam The code in the question is stable and working well, yes. But the topic was really making it as efficient as possible (even at the cost of readability), which this solution provided best for me.

Comment: @SimpleVar, It works, but it is ~2x slower than mine. Also, your code is unsafe. When you test, if you put null as Action, how could you tell that compiler optimization will not throw away the reading of yield (the real calculation of permutation) ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic permutation finder that will iterate through every permutation of a collection and call an evalution function. If the evalution function returns true (it found the answer it was looking for), the permutation finder stops processing.

```
public class PermutationFinder<T>
{
    private T[] items;
    private Predicate<T[]> SuccessFunc;
    private bool success = false;
    private int itemsCount;

    public void Evaluate(T[] items, Predicate<T[]> SuccessFunc)
    {
        this.items = items;
        this.SuccessFunc = SuccessFunc;
        this.itemsCount = items.Count();

        Recurse(0);
    }

    private void Recurse(int index)
    {
        T tmp;

        if (index == itemsCount)
            success = SuccessFunc(items);
        else
        {
            for (int i = index; i < itemsCount; i++)
            {
                tmp = items[index];
                items[index] = items[i];
                items[i] = tmp;

                Recurse(index + 1);

                if (success)
                    break;

                tmp = items[index];
                items[index] = items[i];
                items[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple implementation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Start();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        string[] items = new string[5];
        items[0] = "A";
        items[1] = "B";
        items[2] = "C";
        items[3] = "D";
        items[4] = "E";
        new PermutationFinder<string>().Evaluate(items, Evaluate);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public bool Evaluate(string[] items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", items[0], items[1], items[2], items[3], items[4]));
        bool someCondition = false;

        if (someCondition)
            return true;  // Tell the permutation finder to stop.

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saved items.Count to a variable.  The code as posted now takes ~ .55 seconds to iterate a list of ten items.  The code in the original post takes ~ 2.22 seconds for the same list.

Comment: For a list of 12 items (39,916,800 permutations) this code takes ~ 1 min 13 seconds vs. ~ 2 min 40 seconds for code in the original post.

Comment: My current code is ~1.3-1.5sec for 11 elements. The fact is, you're doing `2N!` swaps when the minimum required swaps are `N!`.

Comment: I would expect at least a x1.5 difference between our versions, since I do nearly `N!` swaps (`kN!` where `k` is very close to `1`), so I assume my computer is simply a bit slower.

Comment: How do you do you do it in N! swaps?  Do you have to iterate the list multiple times?  That might be more expensive than swapping.  I dont understand why you call CompareTo.  If you are looking for all permutations you just need to swap positions.  I suppose I'm missing something since I dont really understand "lexicographic".

Comment: My current algorithm only runs on integers and I don't iterate the list multiple times. I only have recursion which has two `if`'s and a `for` of swaps. I do not even compare values. To get permutations of `T[x]` elements, I generate an array of integers `I[x] {0,1,2...x-1}`, and go over it's permutations, indexing from it into `T`.

Comment: This algorithm is ~3 times slower than my implementation of Knuth's. On 12 elements it takes 33169ms compared to 11941ms. The order isn't strictly lexicographical either.

Comment: Also it's about ~2 times slower than the algorithm in the original post so your timing measurements must be incorrect.

Comment: Even making my implementation of Knuth's generic this algorithm is still more than twice as slow but the original algorithm is only slightly slower. On 12 elements: This 33169ms. Knuth's 15293ms. Original 17356ms.

Comment: Although comparing strings this algorithm seems to be more than 3 times as fast (though still not ordering lexicographically).

Comment: @SaniHuttunen  What do you mean "comparing strings"?  Line for line as posted this code is much faster than the original post.

Comment: @Sam: Try your algorithm with an `int array` instead of `string array` and you'll see it's slower. Remember to exclude all print statements.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen  The evaluation function is just for demonstration.  If you want apples-to-apples comparisons of each of these algorithms set the evaluation function to do nothing in each of them (or set it to do exactly the same thing in each of them).  The times I posted are just for the algorithm to iterate through the permutations.

Comment: @Sam: My timings are just that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive implementation with complexity `O(n * n!)`<sup>1</sup> based on swapping of the elements of an array. The array is initialised with values from `1, 2, ..., n`.

```
using System;

namespace Exercise
{
class Permutations
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int setSize = 3;
        FindPermutations(setSize);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* Method: FindPermutations(n) */
    private static void FindPermutations(int n)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }
        int iEnd = arr.Length - 1;
        Permute(arr, iEnd);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    /* Method: Permute(arr) */
    private static void Permute(int[] arr, int iEnd)
    {
        if (iEnd == 0)
        {
            PrintArray(arr);
            return;
        }

        Permute(arr, iEnd - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < iEnd; i++)
        {
            swap(ref arr[i], ref arr[iEnd]);
            Permute(arr, iEnd - 1);
            swap(ref arr[i], ref arr[iEnd]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

On each recursive step we swap the last element with the current element pointed to by the local variable in the `for` loop and then we indicate the uniqueness of the swapping by: incrementing the local variable of the `for` loop and decrementing the termination condition of the `for` loop, which is initially set to the number of the elements in the array, when the latter becomes zero we terminate the recursion.

Here are the helper functions:

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
        Method: PrintArray()

    */
    private static void PrintArray(int[] arr, string label = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(label);
        Console.Write("{");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i]);
            if (i < arr.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(", ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("}");
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: swap(ref int a, ref int b)

    */
    private static void swap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
```

---

<sup>1. There are `n!` permutations of `n` elements to be printed.</sup>

Comment: Nice and neat solution for general purposes. However in terms of speed it falls behind. But +1 for good code, since most coders are likely to prefer readability for most uses.

Comment: Is there a way to make this return combinations? If so, does it have to create permutations first?

Answer (score 1):

There's an accessible introduction to the algorithms and survey of implementations in Steven Skiena's [*Algorithm Design Manual*](http://www.algorist.com/) (chapter 14.4 in the second edition)

Skiena references D. Knuth. The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4 Fascicle 2: Generating All Tuples and Permutations. Addison Wesley, 2005.

Comment: The link is broken for me, although Google finds that website as well, so it's weird. Pinging to it in CMD results with timed-outs, so I can only guess the link is actually broken.

Comment: I think the author's website is down. Resort to Amazon, or your library.

Comment: @MattHickford The book has some good information there, but nothing that can practically help me.

Comment: I imagine Knuth is comprehensive but I don't have a copy.

Comment: I didn't hear of Knuth algorithm before, but turns out my algorithm is pretty much his.

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if there are really order of magnitude improvements to be found.  If there are, then C# needs fundamental improvement.  Furthermore doing anything interesting with your permutation will generally take more work than generating it.  So the cost of generating is going to be insignificant in the overall scheme of things.

That said, I would suggest trying the following things.  You have already tried iterators.  But have you tried having a function that takes a closure as input, then then calls that closure for each permutation found?  Depending on internal mechanics of C#, this may be faster.

Similarly, have you tried having a function that returns a closure that will iterate over a specific permutation?

With either approach, there are a number of micro-optimizations you can experiment with.  For instance you can sort your input array, and after that you always know what order it is in.  For example you can have an array of bools indicating whether that element is less than the next one, and rather than do comparisons, you can just look at that array.

Comment: +1 For good information. Using closure will maybe somewhat make it faster, but only by a tiny bit. I would imagine that it only saves a few stack operations of copying the pointer to the array, and little stuff like that - nothing significant, though. The second idea you've suggested - using a boolean array - might make a good change! I'll try that and come back to you :)

Comment: The bools idea didn't turn out to be helpful at all... I still need to compare non-neighbor values when searching for the "swap partner" in the "tail", and accessing a bool in an array isn't much different than comparing two integers. Managing a second array wasted time in this case. But nice idea.

Comment: @YoryeNathan But you are now in a position to try other things.  For instance loop unrolling.  Emit a perm.  Then swap the last two and emit the next perm.  Then go back to your more complex logic, secure in the knowledge that you know the last two elements are reversed.  This skips the full logic for half of perms, and skips one comparison for the other half of perms.  You can try unrolling farther - at some point you'll hit cache issues and it will not be worthwhile.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I doubt it will matter that much. It basically saves me just a few variables declared and stepping in and immediately out of two loops, and a single comparison between two elements. The comparison might be significant if the elements were class instances that implement IComparable with some logic, but then again, in such case, I would use an array of integers {0, 1, 2, ...} to indicates indexing into the array of elements, for fast comparison.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, it was a great idea! It cuts the time in by much! Thanks! Waiting to see if any thing better comes up, and considering marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I created an algorithm slightly faster than Knuth's one:

> 11 elements:
>
> mine: 0.39 seconds
>
> Knuth's: 0.624 seconds
>
> 13 elements:
>
> mine: 56.615 seconds
>
> Knuth's: 98.681 seconds

Here's my code in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n=11;
    int a,b,c,i,tmp;
    int end=(int)Math.floor(n/2);
    int[][] pos = new int[end+1][2];
    int[] perm = new int[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) perm[i]=i;

    while(true)
    {
        //this is where you can use the permutations (perm)
        i=0;
        c=n;

        while(pos[i][1]==c-2 && pos[i][0]==c-1)
        {
            pos[i][0]=0;
            pos[i][1]=0;
            i++;
            c-=2;
        }

        if(i==end) System.exit(0);

        a=(pos[i][0]+1)%c+i;
        b=pos[i][0]+i;

        tmp=perm[b];
        perm[b]=perm[a];
        perm[a]=tmp;

        if(pos[i][0]==c-1)
        {
            pos[i][0]=0;
            pos[i][1]++;
        }
        else
        {
            pos[i][0]++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is my algorithm only works for odd numbers of elements. I wrote this code quickly so I'm pretty sure there's a better way to implement my idea to get better performance, but I don't really have the time to work on it right now to optimize it and solve the issue when the number of elements is even.

It's one swap for every permutation and it uses a really simple way to know which elements to swap.

I wrote an explanation of the method behind the code on my blog: http://antoinecomeau.blogspot.ca/2015/01/fast-generation-of-all-permutations.html

Comment: Seems interesting, though it seems to be somewhat slower than my current implementation (marked as answer). I'd love to understand it, though. Also wondering how you actually timed the performance with a broken code (`new int[end + 1][2]` should become `new int[end + 1][]` with an appropriate loop init following)

Comment: Since we talk about performance, get rid of the jagged arrays and use stride instead.

Comment: permutations are not generated in order with this algorithm

Answer (score 1):

As the author of this question was asking about an algorithm:

> [...] generating a single permutation, at a time, and continuing only if necessary

I would suggest considering Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm.

[Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)

Beautifully explained [here](http://typeocaml.com/2015/05/05/permutation/)

Answer (score 0):

It's 1 am and I was watching TV and thought of this same question, but with string values.

Given a word find all permutations.  You can easily modify this to handle an array, sets, etc.

Took me a bit to work it out, but the solution I came up was this:

```
string word = "abcd";

List<string> combinations = new List<string>();

for(int i=0; i<word.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i < j)
            combinations.Add(word[i] + word.Substring(j) + word.Substring(0, i) + word.Substring(i + 1, j - (i + 1)));
        else if (i > j)
        {
            if(i== word.Length -1)
                combinations.Add(word[i] + word.Substring(0, i));
            else
                combinations.Add(word[i] + word.Substring(0, i) + word.Substring(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's the same code as above, but with some comments

```
string word = "abcd";

List<string> combinations = new List<string>();

//i is the first letter of the new word combination
for(int i=0; i<word.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
    {
        //add the first letter of the word, j is past i so we can get all the letters from j to the end
        //then add all the letters from the front to i, then skip over i (since we already added that as the beginning of the word)
        //and get the remaining letters from i+1 to right before j.
        if (i < j)
            combinations.Add(word[i] + word.Substring(j) + word.Substring(0, i) + word.Substring(i + 1, j - (i + 1)));
        else if (i > j)
        {
            //if we're at the very last word no need to get the letters after i
            if(i== word.Length -1)
                combinations.Add(word[i] + word.Substring(0, i));
            //add i as the first letter of the word, then get all the letters up to i, skip i, and then add all the lettes after i
            else
                combinations.Add(word[i] + word.Substring(0, i) + word.Substring(i + 1));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
/**
 * http://marknelson.us/2002/03/01/next-permutation/
 * Rearranges the elements into the lexicographically next greater permutation and returns true.
 * When there are no more greater permutations left, the function eventually returns false.
 */

// next lexicographical permutation

template <typename T>
bool next_permutation(T &arr[], int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
{
    int i = lastIndex;
    while (i > firstIndex)
    {
        int ii = i--;
        T curr = arr[i];
        if (curr < arr[ii])
        {
            int j = lastIndex;
            while (arr[j] <= curr) j--;
            Swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            while (ii < lastIndex)
                Swap(arr[ii++], arr[lastIndex--]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
/**
 * Swaps two variables or two array elements.
 * using references/pointers to speed up swapping.
 */
template<typename T>
void Swap(T &var1, T &var2)
{
    T temp;
    temp = var1;
    var1 = var2;
    var2 = temp;
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
// driver program to test above function
#define N 3

void OnStart()
{
    int i, x[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) x[i] = i + 1;

    printf("The %i! possible permutations with %i elements:", N, N);

    do
    {
        printf("%s", ArrayToString(x));

    } while (next_permutation(x, 0, N - 1));

}

// Output:
// The 3! possible permutations with 3 elements:
// "1,2,3"
// "1,3,2"
// "2,1,3"
// "2,3,1"
// "3,1,2"
// "3,2,1"
```

Comment: This code is hard to understand. It makes 0 sense to be terse with variable names in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Permutations are the different ordered arrangements of an n-element
// array. An n-element array has exactly n! full-length permutations.

// This iterator object allows to iterate all full length permutations
// one by one of an array of n distinct elements.

// The iterator changes the given array in-place.

// Permutations('ABCD') => ABCD  DBAC  ACDB  DCBA
//                         BACD  BDAC  CADB  CDBA
//                         CABD  ADBC  DACB  BDCA
//                         ACBD  DABC  ADCB  DBCA
//                         BCAD  BADC  CDAB  CBDA
//                         CBAD  ABDC  DCAB  BCDA

// count of permutations = n!

// Heap's algorithm (Single swap per permutation)
// http://www.quickperm.org/quickperm.php
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/36634935/4208440
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm


// My implementation of Heap's algorithm:

template<typename T>
class PermutationsIterator
{
 int b, e, n;
 int c[32];  /* control array: mixed radix number in rising factorial base.
             the i-th digit has base i, which means that the digit must be
             strictly less than i. The first digit is always 0,  the second
             can be 0 or 1, the third 0, 1 or 2, and so on.
             ArrayResize isn't strictly necessary, int c[32] would suffice
             for most practical purposes. Also, it is much faster */

public:
 PermutationsIterator(T &arr[], int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
 {
  this.b = firstIndex;  // v.begin()
  this.e = lastIndex;   // v.end()
  this.n = e - b + 1;

  ArrayInitialize(c, 0);
 }

 // Rearranges the input array into the next permutation and returns true.
 // When there are no more permutations left, the function returns false.

 bool next(T &arr[])
 {
  // find index to update
  int i = 1;

  // reset all the previous indices that reached the maximum possible values
  while (c[i] == i)
  {
   c[i] = 0;
   ++i;
  }

  // no more permutations left
  if (i == n)
   return false;

  // generate next permutation
  int j = (i & 1) == 1 ? c[i] : 0;    // IF i is odd then j = c[i] otherwise j = 0.
  swap(arr[b + j], arr[b + i]);       // generate a new permutation from previous permutation using a single swap

  // Increment that index
  ++c[i];
  return true;
 }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this algo on rosetta code  and it is really the fastest one I tried. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#C

```js
/* Boothroyd method; exactly N! swaps, about as fast as it gets */
void boothroyd(int *x, int n, int nn, int callback(int *, int))
{
 int c = 0, i, t;
 while (1) {
  if (n > 2) boothroyd(x, n - 1, nn, callback);
  if (c >= n - 1) return;
 
  i = (n & 1) ? 0 : c;
  c++;
  t = x[n - 1], x[n - 1] = x[i], x[i] = t;
  if (callback) callback(x, nn);
 }
}
 
/* entry for Boothroyd method */
void perm2(int *x, int n, int callback(int*, int))
{
 if (callback) callback(x, n);
 boothroyd(x, n, n, callback);
}
```

Comment: This code is hard to understand. It makes 0 sense to be terse with variable names in this instance.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to calculate the number of possible permutations you can avoid all that hard work above and use something like this (contrived in c#):

```
public static class ContrivedUtils 
{
    public static Int64 Permutations(char[] array)
    {
        if (null == array || array.Length == 0) return 0;

        Int64 permutations = array.Length;

        for (var pos = permutations; pos > 1; pos--)
            permutations *= pos - 1;

        return permutations;
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
var permutations = ContrivedUtils.Permutations("1234".ToCharArray());
// output is: 24
var permutations = ContrivedUtils.Permutations("123456789".ToCharArray());
// output is: 362880
```

Comment: Yeah, it's really not that hard to implement factoring. The idea is to have the permutations themselves, though. Not to mention, you would be better off with just `.Permutations(4)` instead of a meaningless array of chars.

Comment: true, but every time I've been asked this question in interviews the input is always a string of chars, so it seemed worthwhile to present it that way.

Comment: And yet, the whole answer remains irrelevant to the subject.

Answer (score -2):

Simple C# recursive solution by swapping, for the initial call the index must be 0

```
    static public void Permute<T>(List<T> input, List<List<T>> permutations, int index)
    {
        if (index == input.Count - 1)
        {
            permutations.Add(new List<T>(input));
            return;
        }

        Permute(input, permutations, index + 1);

        for (int i = index+1 ; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            //swap
            T temp = input[index];
            input[index] = input[i];
            input[i] = temp;

            Permute(input, permutations, index + 1);

            //swap back
            temp = input[index];
            input[index] = input[i];
            input[i] = temp;
        }
    }
```