# Find all Possible pair combination of 2 arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sequence

**EDIT: Please note, this question is not the same as "Generating all Possible Combinations" Im not looking for a simple Cartesian Product**

I need to write a function that produces array of all possible pair combinations of 2 given arrays. So for example:

1. a, b, c ...
2. x, y ...

I need to find all pair combinations of these numbers, so it will look like:

- Combination 1: a-x, b-y, c
- Combination 2: a-y, b-x, c
- Combination 3: a-x, c-y, b
- Combination 4: a-y, c-x, b
- and so on....

The result should be List of List of Pair, also Pair can contain only 1 number, if initial sets are not equal

thanks

-alex

Comment: Should 'a-x' and 'x-a' be a different combination in your application?

Comment: @sriram-sakthivel excuse me, but I dont see how my question duplicates the one you posted, Im not looking for a simple cartesion product, I need a list of unique combinations, where combination is a list of pairs

Comment: @Max yes, but its not necessary since i can swap arrays and run it again. Also a-x is not a combination, combination is a full set of pairs: a-x, b-y, c

Comment: I reopened the question, It will be better to add your attempt to the question.

Comment: Is a-x, b, c, y possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the arrays be A and B. Assume that A is not smaller than B and that every element in B must be paired. [For each permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208446/generating-permutations-of-a-set-most-efficiently) A' of A, generate a pairing where A'[0] is paired with B[0], and A'[1] is paired with B[1], and ..., and the leftover elements of A' are unpaired.

Comment: Thanks, Its what I did, I paired array A to B with corresponding index, then at the end of each permutation cycle I rotated arrays, to get new combination