# Generating permutations of a set - efficiently and with distinction

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, recursion, permutation

I'm building on code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208446/generating-permutations-of-a-set-most-efficiently). I'd like to generate all permutations of a set, for example (taken from the thread):

```
Collection: 1, 2, 3
Permutations: {1, 2, 3}
              {1, 3, 2}
              {2, 1, 3}
              {2, 3, 1}
              {3, 1, 2}
              {3, 2, 1}
```

There are [image] possible permutations for every set, but this is not what I'd like to achieve. Take, for consideration, following set:

[image]

This would yield [image] permutations, an extreme amout of [image]. This would take an extraordinary long time to compute, as each zero is being considered unique.

Rather than that, I'd like to only generate **distinct permutations**. If we do that, there are only

[image]

permutations [remaining](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutations%20of%20%7B20%2C10%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D), as 18 items are identical (k).

Now, I could run the code from the mentioned thread and store the results in a HashSet, eliminating the duplicate permutations. However, that would be extremely inefficient. I'm looking for an algorithm to generate permutations with distinction directly.

Comment: I'm confused. The code in the linked thread is doing a lexicographic increment, which actually works fine on multisets with duplicate elements, no HashSet required.

Comment: Well I would say that all you need to do is use distinct subset of the input before applying the algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat It works fine, but it takes a long time to compute. If I don't use the HashSet, I would have 2.4 * 10^18 results.

Comment: No, I mean that the generated permutations are pairwise distinct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Swap algorithm to find permutations you can directly exclude the parts that produce duplicate permutations. This algorithm is available on internet and you can find more information about it.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> set = new List<int>
    {
        20, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
    var permutes = Permute(set);

    Console.WriteLine(permutes.Count); // outputs 58140
}

private static List<int[]> Permute(List<int> set)
{
    List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>(); 

    Action<int> permute = null;
    permute = start =>
    {
        if (start == set.Count)
        {
            result.Add(set.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            List<int> swaps = new List<int>();
            for (int i = start; i < set.Count; i++)
            {
                if (swaps.Contains(set[i])) continue; // skip if we already done swap with this item
                swaps.Add(set[i]);

                Swap(set, start, i);
                permute(start + 1); 
                Swap(set, start, i);
            }
        }
    };

    permute(0);

    return result;
}

private static void Swap(List<int> set, int index1, int index2)
{
    int temp = set[index1];
    set[index1] = set[index2];
    set[index2] = temp;
}
```

Here is the image that shows how swap algorithm works.

[image]

So you have `{A,B,C}, {A,C,B}, {B,A,C}, {B,C,A}, {C,B,A}, {C,A,B}`

Now Consider `A` and `B` are equal. Ive edited the image with photoshop (sorry if im terrible at it!) And replaced `B` with `A`. As you can see in the image

[image]

Ive identified duplicates in image. If you skip them you will have `{A,A,C}, {A,C,A}, {C,A,A}`

You have to store items that are swapped so if the items are equal and we already had that swap we just skip to prevent dupes

```
if (swaps.Contains(set[i])) continue; // skip if we already done swap with this item
swaps.Add(set[i]); // else add it to the list of swaps.
```

For test if you delete this part then this algorithm will produce duplicate permutations and console will output `n!`.

Comment: I've tested this with Permute(new List<int>() {20, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}), however it will trigger an OutOfMemoryException as list will grow over 10 million (the actual result should be 58410)

Comment: @Jacobus21 thanks for the information. ive fixed it by remembering swaps. test it now ;)

Comment: Wonderful! It takes about 28 seconds to permute { 20, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, which is two seconds faster than my method. Is there any way to further optimize it?

Comment: My bad, I was writing results into a list which slowed things down significantly. It's really fast!

Answer (score 2):

This is so far the best solution I've come up with. Suggestions for optimization welcome. It returns exactly n!/k! items.

It takes about one second to permute { 20, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }.

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Permute(int[] list)
{
    if (list.Length > 1)
    {    
        int n = list[0];
        foreach (int[] subPermute in Permute(list.Skip(1).ToArray()))
        {    
            for (int index = 0; index <= subPermute.Length; index++)
            {
                int[] pre = subPermute.Take(index).ToArray();
                int[] post = subPermute.Skip(index).ToArray();

                if (post.Contains(n))
                    continue;

                yield return pre.Concat(new[] { n }).Concat(post).ToArray();
            }    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive! Thanks for including an approx time

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it:

```
Knuths
1. Find the largest index j such that a[j] < a[j + 1]. If no
such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.

{20,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
   >  > = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
```

Oops, there is no index `j` such that `a[j] < a[j + 1]`. But since we want *all* distinct permutations, we can sort each array and guarantee we start at the beginning:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,20}

1. Find the largest index j such that a[j] < a[j + 1]. If no
such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.

j = 18 since a[18] < a[19]

2. Find the largest index l such that a[j] < a[l]. Since j + 1
is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies j < l.

l = 19 since a[18] < a[19]

3. Swap a[j] with a[l].

{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,10}

4. Reverse the sequence from a[j + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,10}
```

Let's do a few more:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,10}
yields {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,20}
yields {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,20,0}
yields {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,0,10}
yields {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,10,0}
yields {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,20}
...
```

As you can see, the large elements are steadily (and distinctly) moving left until:

```
{10,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
yields {20,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

And ends without duplicating permutations.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this problem before. You just need to sort the array first and then use a boolean[] visited array to mark elements which you have visited. My solution using backtracking, in Java:

```
public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permuteUnique(int[] num) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[num.length];

        Arrays.sort(num);
        helper(result, list, num, visited);

        return result;
    }

    private void helper(List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> list,
            int[] num, boolean[] visited) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (visited[i]
                    || (i > 0 && num[i] == num[i - 1] && !visited[i - 1])) {
                continue;
            }
            list.add(num[i]);
            visited[i] = true;
            if (list.size() == num.length) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
            } else {
                helper(result, list, num, visited);
            }
            list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            visited[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```