# Partial Combinations/Permutations in C# - e.g. A,B,C = {A,B}, {A,C}, {B,C}

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation

There are many [brilliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208446/generating-permutations-of-a-set-most-efficiently) implementations for Permutations - I chose Sam's answer in the link.

I also understand there is a difference between permutations and combinations but I don't know how to word this properly.

I need guidance on getting all unique partial combinations please, e.g.

```
A,B,C = {A,B}, {A,C}, {B,C}
A,B,C,D = {A,B,C},{A,B,D},{B,C,D},{A,C,D},{A,B}, {A,C}, {B,C}
```

From here I will pass this to the permutation function to get me all available
permutations,
 e.g. `{A,B}, {B,A}, {A,C}, {C,A}` etc.

How can I get these (partial) subsets of the greater set?

Comment: What sort of signature do you want on the method? Is it always returning sets that have one item missing or might you want to pass in a four item set and get all 2 item subsets? Or might you want to get all 2 and all three subsets? Its a little unclear from your examples exactly what exactly you are wanting...

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, I updated the question now to address that. For e.g. 4 items it would be all 2 items subsets and 3 items subsets. Thus all combinations > 1 and < GetUpperBound

Comment: Why are {A,B,C}, {A}, {B} and {C} not included in the first case? Those are also subsets of {A,B,C}

Comment: Apologies @JanKukacka, I updated the question now, I was interested in only subsets but not full sets and not single sets. It is all combinations in between that I am battling with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer The question is asking for all partial combinations, *not* for all permutations.  Very different.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I realized that a bit too late, but I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to do recursively. You go through a virtual tree in the `GetSubCombinations` function, always returning the set without the current element first and then with the current element. On the last level (the first part of the `GetSubCombinations` function) you generate the lists that are being returned, either including the last element or being empty.

Code follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


class Program {
    private static IEnumerable<List<char>> GetSubCombinations(char[] elements, uint startingPos)
    {
        // Leaf condition
        if (startingPos == elements.Length - 1)
        {
            yield return new List<char> {elements[startingPos]};
            yield return new List<char>();
            yield break;
        }

        // node splitting
        foreach (var list in GetSubCombinations(elements, startingPos + 1))
        {
            yield return list;
            list.Add(elements[startingPos]);
            yield return list;
            list.Remove(elements[startingPos]);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<List<char>> GetPartialCombinations(char[] elements)
    {
        foreach (var c in GetSubCombinations(elements, 0))
        {
            // Here you can filter out trivial combinations,
            // e.g. all elements, individual elements and the empty set
            if (c.Count > 1 && c.Count < elements.Length)
                yield return c;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args) {
        char[] elements = new char[] {'A', 'B', 'C'};
        foreach (var combination in GetPartialCombinations(elements))
        {
            foreach (char elem in combination)
                System.Console.Write(elem + ", ");
            System.Console.Write("\n");
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between permutation to a combination is that in a permutation the order matters.

From what I understand you want all the **Combinations**,
Thus all combinations that don't fill the exact set (You want to make a subset)

**EX:**

So for `S = {A,B,C,D}`, an example of a partial combination would be `{A,C,B}` as it doesn't care about the order and it doesn't contain the full set (ie. it is a subset of S)

The formula for Combination is `N choose K`

So your set has 4 elements (N) and you want a set of 3 or less (K)

```
So N!/K!(N-K)! 
3: = 4!/3!(4-3)! = (1x2x3x4)/(1x2x3)(1) = 4
2: = 4!/2!(2)! = 1x2x3x4/(1x2x1x2) = 6
1: = 4!/1!(4-1)! = 1x2x3x4/1x2x3 = 4
```

Thus answer is **14**

If you want some code on how to implement a combination calculation: [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802822/all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-values)

```
private static void GetCombination(List<int> list)
{
    double count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);
    for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
    {
        string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(list.Count, '0');
        for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str[j] == '1')
            {
                Console.Write(list[j]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the answer part. (It is in there now)

Comment: In what way does this generate all partial combination subsets?  It appears to merely count how many there are, not actually generate the subsets.

Comment: @TristanvanDam that is what is required please. I excluded the full amount of elements and single elements, but yes that is exactly it.

Comment: This is for generating the subset where you want three letters of the four. Ie: {A,B,C}, {B,C,D}, {C,D,A}, {D,A,B}. Note how they are in order as it is a combination. YOU would do the same for each relevant subset (S2) and (S1)

Comment: @PeterPitLock I have rewritten it to make it more clear