# All unique combinations of rectangles by reordering and flipping

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

We are given N rectangular frames of different sizes (duplicates are allowed). Write a program to find all unique ways we can reorder these frames by exchanging their order and flipping them.

Input:

```
3
2 3
2 2
3 2
```

Output:

```
12
(2, 2) | (2, 3) | (2, 3)
(2, 2) | (2, 3) | (3, 2)
(2, 2) | (3, 2) | (2, 3)
(2, 2) | (3, 2) | (3, 2)
(2, 3) | (2, 2) | (2, 3)
(2, 3) | (2, 2) | (3, 2)
(2, 3) | (2, 3) | (2, 2)
(2, 3) | (3, 2) | (2, 2)
(3, 2) | (2, 2) | (2, 3)
(3, 2) | (2, 2) | (3, 2)
(3, 2) | (2, 3) | (2, 2)
(3, 2) | (3, 2) | (2, 2)
```

Here is my code so far in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Frames
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var frames = new Tuple<int, int>[n * 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i += 2)
            {
                var strs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                frames[i] = new Tuple<int, int>(int.Parse(strs[0]), int.Parse(strs[1]));
                frames[i + 1] = new Tuple<int, int>(frames[i].Item2, frames[i].Item1);
            }

            Array.Sort(frames);

            Recursion(frames, 0, n, new Tuple<int, int>[n], new bool[frames.Length]);
        }

        static void Recursion(Tuple<int, int>[] frames, int position, int n, Tuple<int, int>[] current, bool[] used)
        {
            if (position == n)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", (IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>)current));
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (used[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                used[i] = true;
                current[position] = frames[i];
                Recursion(frames, position + 1, n, current, used);
                used[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to treat both rotations of the frame as used and then exclude duplicates.
Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: For your 12 example, aren't the first two rows the same (you have just rotated the third column 90 degrees)?

Comment: yes you are allowed to rotate and reorder the rectangles

Comment: Can you explain what your inputs mean? What does `3` mean? What about `2 3`? Also https://betterexplained.com/articles/easy-permutations-and-combinations/ may be worth a read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208446/generating-permutations-of-a-set-most-efficiently may be a starting point.

Comment: 3 is the number of rectangles (frames) and on each line you get the sizes of the two sides of the frames. And thank you for the article I'll have a look

Comment: For eliminating duplicates, **1)** build up a `List<string>` and use a distinct on it.  **2)** keep a `HashSet<string>` with combinations made and check before presenting a 'new' one.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is an option since the Memory Limit for this task is quite high at 45MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the directions about the hashset. Here is the working solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Frames
{
    class Program
    {
        static SortedSet<string> output = new SortedSet<string>();

        static void Main()
        {
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var frames = new Tuple<int, int>[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var strs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                frames[i] = new Tuple<int, int>(int.Parse(strs[0]), int.Parse(strs[1]));
            }

            Recursion(frames, 0, new Tuple<int, int>[n], new bool[n]);

            Console.WriteLine(output.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
        }

        static void Recursion(Tuple<int, int>[] frames, int position, Tuple<int, int>[] current, bool[] used)
        {
            if (position == frames.Length)
            {
                output.Add(string.Join(" | ", (IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>)current));
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++)
            {
                if (used[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }

                used[i] = true;

                current[position] = frames[i];
                Recursion(frames, position + 1, current, used);

                current[position] = new Tuple<int, int>(frames[i].Item2, frames[i].Item1);
                Recursion(frames, position + 1, current, used);

                used[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```