# What is faster, nested loops or many loops in sequence?

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a 2D array of size [3000,3] and I have to find Euclidean Distances between the 3000 values in first dimension 3 times (second dimension).
What I am doing now is makin a nested for loop, I looked for ways of making it faster, but the only think I found was setting up a structure as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789028/faster-alternative-to-nested-loops).

Perhaps doing 3 for loops is faster than doing a nested loop. Does anyone know how the processing time goes in this case?

Comment: Why don't you test them and see which one is faster?

Comment: @roryap stole my question haha. Marcelo, I'd suggest you to try it out yourself.

Comment: See this: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't matter at all whether you run a loop three times via nested-loop or via separate loops, as long as the amount of iterations are the same.

If you can improve your algorithm, so that you need fewer iterations (fewer than 3000 x 3), that might get you somewhere.