# c# combination process time too slow and out of memory exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, combinations

I have n-elements of this kind

```
 public class Ricerca:IComparable
{
    public int id;

    public double Altezza;
    public double lunghezza;

    }
```

I need to calculate all the possible combination of this elements, my problem is that the method I am using is too slow when I have a lot of elements and sometimes I get the out of memory exception.

Any suggestions?

thanks for your help

this is how I calculate the combination I found this method in a c# forum I didn't do it

```
  public void allMyCombination(List<Ricerca>Elements,int i,ref List<List<Ricerca>> combinazioni)
    {

        Combinations<Ricerca> combinations = new Combinations<Ricerca>(Elements, i);


         foreach (Ricerca[] combination in combinations)
        {


            List<Ricerca> rsr = new List<Ricerca>() { };
            foreach (Ricerca rsh in combination)



            {

                rsr.Add(rsh);

            }

           // rsr.AddRange(combination);
            combinazioni.Add(rsr);


       }


    }
```

and these Are the classes used:

```
   class Combinations<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    #region Combinations Members
    private ElementSet<T> _Elements;
    private int _Choose;


    /// <param name="elements">the collection of elements</param>
    /// <param name="choose">the length of a combination</param>
    public Combinations(IEnumerable<T> elements, int choose)
        : this(new ElementSet<T>(elements, null), choose)
    {
    }


    /// <param name="elements">the collection of elements</param>
    /// <param name="choose">the length of a combination</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">the comparer used to order the elements</param>
    public Combinations(IEnumerable<T> elements, IComparer<T> comparer, int choose)
        : this(new ElementSet<T>(elements, comparer), choose)
    {
    }

    /// <param name="elements">the collection of elements</param>
    /// <param name="choose">the length of a combination</param>
    public Combinations(ElementSet<T> elements, int choose)
    {
        if (elements == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("elements");
        }
        if (choose < 0 || choose > elements.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("choose");
        }
        _Elements = elements;
        _Choose = choose;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T[]> Members

    /// <seealso cref="IEnumerable{T}.GetEnumerator"/>
    public IEnumerator<T[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_Choose == 0)
        {
            return new ChooseZeroEnumerator();
        }
        else
        {
            return new Enumerator(this);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Enumerator Class
    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T[]>
    {
        #region Enumerator Members
        private Combinations<T> _Combinations;
        private int[] _Indices, _IndicesAt;
        private bool _PastEnd;

        internal Enumerator(Combinations<T> combinations)
        {
            _Combinations = combinations;
            _Indices = new int[_Combinations._Choose];
            _IndicesAt = new int[_Combinations._Elements.Elements.Count];
            Reset();
        }

        private void MoveFirst()
        {

            int currentIndex = 0;
            int usedCurrent = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _Indices.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Assert(currentIndex < _Combinations._Elements.Elements.Count);
                _Indices[i] = currentIndex;
                _IndicesAt[currentIndex]++;
                usedCurrent++;
                if (usedCurrent == _Combinations._Elements.Elements.Values[currentIndex])
                {

                    currentIndex++;
                    usedCurrent = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private void MoveIndex(int index, int offset)
        {
            if (_Indices[index] >= 0 && _Indices[index] < _IndicesAt.Length)
            {
                _IndicesAt[_Indices[index]]--;
            }
            _Indices[index] += offset;
            if (_Indices[index] >= 0 && _Indices[index] < _IndicesAt.Length)
            {
                _IndicesAt[_Indices[index]]++;
            }
        }

        private bool IsFull(int position)
        {
            // True if (position) has as many indices as it can hold.
            return _IndicesAt[position] == _Combinations._Elements.Elements.Values[position];
        }

        private bool CanFitRemainingIndices(int index)
        {
            int space = _Combinations._Elements.ElementsAtOrAfter[_Indices[index]];
            return space >= _Indices.Length - index;
        }

        private bool AdvanceIndex(int index, int doNotReach)
        {
            // First move the index one position to the right.
            MoveIndex(index, 1);
            // If we've found an existing position with no other index, and there's room at-and-to-the-right-of us for all the indices greater than us, we're good.
            if (_Indices[index] < doNotReach)
            {
                if (_IndicesAt[_Indices[index]] == 1)
                {
                    if (CanFitRemainingIndices(index))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // We've either fallen off the right hand edge, or hit a position with another index. If we're index 0, we're past the end of the enumeration. If not, we need to advance the next lower index, then push ourself left as far as possible until we hit another occupied position.
            if (index == 0)
            {
                _PastEnd = true;
                return false;
            }
            if (!AdvanceIndex(index - 1, _Indices[index]))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (IsFull(_Indices[index] - 1))
            {
                _PastEnd = true;
                return false;
            }
            // Move left until the next leftmost element is full, or the current element has an index.
            do
            {
                MoveIndex(index, -1);
            } while (_IndicesAt[_Indices[index]] == 1 && !IsFull(_Indices[index] - 1));
            return true;
        }
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerator<T[]> Members
        public T[] Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Indices[0] == -1 || _PastEnd)
                {
                    // Before first or after last.
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                else
                {
                    T[] current = new T[_Indices.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < _Indices.Length; i++)
                    {
                        current[i] = _Combinations._Elements.Elements.Keys[_Indices[i]];
                    }
                    return current;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerator Members
        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_PastEnd)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (_Indices[0] == -1)
            {
                MoveFirst();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool ret = AdvanceIndex(_Indices.Length - 1, _IndicesAt.Length);
                return ret;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Indices.Length; i++)
            {
                _Indices[i] = -1;
            }
            Array.Clear(_IndicesAt, 0, _IndicesAt.Length);
            _PastEnd = false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    #region ChooseZeroEnumerator Class
    private class ChooseZeroEnumerator : IEnumerator<T[]>
    {
        #region ChooseZeroEnumerator Members
        private enum State
        {
            BeforeBeginning,
            OnElement,
            PastEnd,
        }

        private State _State;

        internal ChooseZeroEnumerator()
        {
            Reset();
        }
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerator<T[]> Members
        public T[] Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (_State == State.OnElement)
                {
                    return new T[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerator Members
        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            switch (_State)
            {
                case State.BeforeBeginning:
                    _State = State.OnElement;
                    return true;

                case State.OnElement:
                case State.PastEnd:
                    _State = State.PastEnd;
                    return false;

                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _State = State.BeforeBeginning;
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

}

  class ElementSet<T>
{
    private SortedList<T, int> _Elements;
    private int _Count;
    private int[] _ElementsAtOrAfter;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new <c>ElementSet</c> from a collection of elements, using the default comparer for the element type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="elements">the elements</param>
    public ElementSet(IEnumerable<T> elements)
        : this(elements, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new <c>ElementSet</c> from a collection of an elements, using a custom comparer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="elements">the elements</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">the comparer</param>
    public ElementSet(IEnumerable<T> elements, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (elements == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("elements");
        }

        SortedDictionary<T, int> sorted = new SortedDictionary<T, int>(comparer);
        foreach (T element in elements)
        {
            int count;
            if (sorted.TryGetValue(element, out count))
            {
                sorted[element] = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sorted[element] = 1;
            }
            _Count++;
        }
        _Elements = new SortedList<T, int>(sorted, comparer);
        _Elements.Capacity = _Elements.Count;
        // Produce the Number of Elements At or After array.
        // This is a cumulative sum of the reverse of the values array.
        if (_Elements.Count > 0)
        {
            _ElementsAtOrAfter = new int[_Elements.Count];
            _ElementsAtOrAfter[_Elements.Count - 1] = _Elements.Values[_Elements.Count - 1];
            for (int i = _Elements.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                _ElementsAtOrAfter[i] = _ElementsAtOrAfter[i + 1] + _Elements.Values[i];
            }
        }
    }

    internal SortedList<T, int> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            return _Elements;
        }
    }

    internal int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _Count;
        }
    }

    internal int[] ElementsAtOrAfter
    {
        get
        {
            return _ElementsAtOrAfter;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share the method that's too slow that you mentioned?

Comment: How are you finding the combinations? Do you need all of them at once, or could you `yield` them one at a time? What would be one combination? (Just asking, because you haven't constrained the double values or the ints)

Comment: sorry I added the code

Comment: Generating combinations could be a really heavy task. Which parameters you use? (number of elements, length of combinations). As an option you could stick to canonical algorithms working in indexes to avoid using List of elements (you need to store elements in a separate array)

Comment: Wild guess, but are you, perhaps, trying to find an optimal/shortest path through a list of locations by listing all possible permutations ("combinations") of those locations? In that case, this approach will not work, as you experience: It's extremely slow or even impossible for your computers' hardware. Problems like that are solved with [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), but it's not the simplest domain in computer science :). A shortest path algorythm often used in games is [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: @sargey do you have a link?

Comment: @Thomas not Actually I am trying to find a combination of cuts in order to reduce to minimum  the waste of material. I have several cuts to perform on coils to get pieces of material I have to find the combinations of cuts to perform that reduces to minimum the waste of Material

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/759447/Csharp-Class-to-generate-Math-Combinations as an example

Comment: Anyway, for me, it looks like you need to benchmark generator to understand what kind of generation speed you could achieve.

Comment: By the way, you haven't provided any numbers you actually want to use. Think you need to calculate c(n,k) to understand what king of problem you are trying to solve. Such as, if you have 1000 elements and would like to generate all the combinations by length 50 that leads to 9460461017585217846063722277728044918729694001668654064793569321343252697198115263280 combinations ) so generation could look like really slow until you understand the numbers

Comment: @SergeyProsin for Example I have to calculate the following combinations I have 250 elements and I have to calculate all the combinations C(250,k) with k=1,............,max where max it's the  maximum number of cut that can be performed on a Coil , max it's CoilHeight/smallestCut so it depends on cases

Comment: The number of combinations depends heavily on k, such as c(250, 1) = 250 but c(250, 125) = 91208366928185711600087718663295946582847985411225264672245111235434562752

Comment: @SergeyProsin I know :-( that where I get the problem , it takes hours literally to my pc to calculate those combinations but I guess there is not a lot I can do right?

Comment: My Idea is you should measure the performance of the generator you are using and calculate c(n,k) to get an estimeate of what time is required to hgenerate that. And the general idea is the same one: you need to have effective generator without any dynamic obejcts such as list etc. because generation here is a key to performance

Comment: this is a complexity problem which can't be solved by optimizing codebase only. In case generation time is inappropriate you need to think on other ways to reduce it: use multithreading, use a cluster to calculate that, think of more effictive algorithm to solve business task to aboid c(n,k) generation or reduce n and k if it makes sence

Comment: @SergeyProsin thanks

Comment: @SergeyProsin Thanks I've been trying to avoid the cases where c(n,k) produces too much combination thank you so much , it's driving me crazy:-)

Comment: If my comments has helped, please, vote for them ;) thanks

Comment: Try to rethink what you are trying to achieve. Maybe trying to get suboptimal result instead of optimal one would allow to use other algorithms with lower complexity

Comment: @SergeyProsin thanks I am trying to do that whish me luck :-)

Comment: Fingers crossed

Comment: You really should upvote the comments by @SergeyProsin. They are gold and have helped you understand your problem much better.

Answer (score 0):

Nice class you found ! Did some testing with it. I added a comparer to your element class. Don't know what your comparer looks like.. but maybe speed can be improved by optimizing it. For my tests, I kept it minimal. See code below.

```
public class Ricerca : IComparable
{
    public double altezza;
    public double lunghezza;

    // added some index to sort by
    public int i = 0;
    public Ricerca(int ci) { altezza = 53; lunghezza = -4.5;  i = ci; }

    // comparator to sort with
    public int CompareTo(object e)
    { return (((Ricerca)e).i > i) ? 1 : (((Ricerca)e).i == i) ? 0 : -1; }
}
```

Two observations,

1. above remarks about zillions of permutations only count when all elements are different. When there are many equal values in the list, the result count is much smaller and operation is much faster. So if this generic class is usable for you, depends not only on list counts, also on the data you are analysing..
2. this is managed code, so memory usage depends on GC. When all indexes are unique, I get 10015005 sets for (29 9), 24 sec runtime and about 900MB consumption. When every second index is equal, I get 0.7 sec runtime and 48MB consumption. You can eliminate this load, when you don't translate the Combinations list to another list, but use the foreach() on combinations itself. My test shows constant memory use, because I dont store the list, I get constant memory consumption of about 18MB with below loop irrespective of parameters. for Elements.Count=29, set size 9 it needs 12 sec.

   ```
   private void doSomething(List<Ricerca> AChosen)
   {
       // perform some task on chosen set
   }

   void Test(List<Ricerca> Elements, int rSetSize)
   {
    Combinations<Ricerca> combinations = new Combinations<Ricerca>(Elements, rSetSize);
    int nReported = 0;
    foreach (Ricerca[] combination in combinations)
    {
       List<Ricerca> chosenPlaces = new List<Ricerca>();
       for (int j = 0; j < combination.Length; j++)
           chosenPlaces.Add(combination[j]);
       doSomething(chosenPlaces); // instance, save only when needed
       nReported++;
    }
   ```

   }