# Finding all possible combinations of numbers 

Tags: c#, permutation, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combination Generator in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774457/combination-generator-in-linq)

I am looking of an algorithm (using C#) that can
find all the combinations of specified numbers.
    Example:
Numbers:
1 2 3
Combinations:
1
2
3
12
13
21
23
31
32
123
132
213
231
312
321

Only rule: No repetitions of numbers

I have looked around [Google](http://google.com), [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), as well as numerous other sites.
I would list some of my code, but I have had no success getting anything to work along the right lines.

EDIT:
The intention of this is using the generated numbers as the positions of characters in a word. I am creating a word finder, so basically this is what it is being used for:

Program generates:
0
1
01
10

From numbers: 0 1

The program got the numbers 0 and 1 from the user inputting for instance "no".

Example code:
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int size = input.Length; //This is where the 0 and 1 come from

Therefore the different combinations would rearrange the letters, using the length of the inputted word as the base, then comparing it to a word list, I could find existing words.

Comment: You should still post your code and ask specific questions.  SO likes to see _some_ effort in the question asker's part.

Comment: I noted No repetitions. The link given is something different

Comment: Nothing that I have made so far has done any good for this question. If I find something that can benefit this then I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is a proper utilization of recursion. I think [Permutations in C# Using Recursion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37215/Permutations-in-C-Using-Recursion) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This has helped a lot... Thanks!

Comment: @Jason753951, welcome. its much simpler.

Comment: This gives me something to think about... I was nowhere when I asked this question.

Comment: @Nero: A link on its own is not an answer.  If that link ever breaks, your "answer" is useless.  Paraphrase here, at the very least.  The link should support your answer, not *be* it.

Comment: @cHao: just thought it would provide an instant help. but it's OK, points noted.

Answer (score -1):

I'll do more research as I have time and try to improve my answer.

Your program is dealing with combinatorial math (which you can google and read about). There is a formula for calculating your answer. Your question falls under the "Pick x from n" variety with respect to order.

Comment: Please withhold posting an answer until you have a proper answer.