# Generate Combinations of generic list

Tags: c#, linq, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I need to create a list from another list that contains every combination possible.  In researching possible solutions I have found many interesting approaches but all seem to generate results based on the count of records provided.  I need the combinations to increase to a max threshold.

i.e.  consider the following array

1,2,3,4,5

I need the results to look similar to (threshold is 3 in this example)

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
1,3,4
2,3,5... etc
```

In actuality, the data will be IEnumerable.  I used a simple int[] to illustrate the desired results.

Comment: Your question is quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/774457/2145211.  Did you look at the answers there?

Answer (score 5):

My solution uses a simple recursive algorithm to create the combinations:

- When we walk through the sequence we can immediately return a sequence that only holds the current value. I have written a simple extension method to create an IEnumerable for a single item.
- Next we recursively generate all combinations for the remaining elements with the threshold reduced by 1 and combine each of them with the current value.

I assume that elements should not be repeated (i.e. { 1, 1 } or { 1, 2, 1 } are not allowed). If you want to allow repeated elements you can remove the `remaining` variable and replace it with `values` in the recursive call to `GetCombinations`.

Please note the use of the [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword. This means that the code uses deferred execution. There is no need to store any intermediate results before you actually enumerate the result.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, int threshold)
{
    var remaining = values;

    foreach (T value in values)
    {
        yield return value.Yield();

        if (threshold < 2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        remaining = remaining.Skip(1);

        foreach (var combination in GetCombinations(remaining, threshold - 1))
        {
            yield return value.Yield().Concat(combination);
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
{
    yield return item;
}
```

For the integer array { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } the output is:

```
1
1, 2
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 2, 5
1, 3
1, 3, 4
1, 3, 5
1, 4
1, 4, 5
1, 5
2
2, 3
2, 3, 4
2, 3, 5
2, 4
2, 4, 5
2, 5
3
3, 4
3, 4, 5
3, 5
4
4, 5
5
```

Comment: I like this one better :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a solution to find the combinations for a particular count (which you've said you have), let's say of the signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(
    IList<T> source, int count)
```

Then you can easily get the combinations for all counts by calling it N times:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(IList<T> source)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count)
            .SelectMany(i => Combinations(source, i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Combinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int threshold)
{
    var comboBuilder = new List<T>();
    foreach (var combo in EnumerateCombos(items, comboBuilder, 0, threshold))
    {
        yield return combo;
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<T[]> EnumerateCombos<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, List<T> currentCombo, 
                                                   int startIndex, int threshold)
{
    if (currentCombo.Count >= threshold) { yield break; }

    for (int i = startIndex; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
        //Skip past the items we've already gone through in the current combo:
        var item = items.Skip(i).First();

        //Create a new combination with the next available item:
        currentCombo.Add(item);
        yield return currentCombo.ToArray();

        //Repeat the process with the rest of the remaining items:
        foreach (var combo in EnumerateCombos(items, currentCombo, i + 1, threshold))
        {
            yield return combo;
        }

        //Recursion cleanup:
        currentCombo.RemoveAt(currentCombo.Count - 1);
    }
}
```