# Generate all possible permutations from given letters in C#

Tags: c#, permutation, words

Suppose I have following characters in a string:

```
string s = "acn"
```

I want to write a function in C# to display following words:

> acn
>
> anc
>
> cna
>
> can
>
> nac
>
> nca

I have tried these but I am still confused.

[Using Permutations in .NET for Improved Systems Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302371.aspx)

[Implement a function that prints all possible combinations of the characters in a string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28248/implement-a-function-that-prints-all-possible-combinations-of-the-characters-in/28249)

Comment: so the out put should have the same number of character but with different combinations ? Is my understanding about you question right?

Comment: yes @SilentCoder

Comment: Your question is [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: What if the string is `aan`? What should the outputs be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: aan, ana, naa @mjwills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EnumerableExtensions

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774457/combination-generator-in-linq#12012418
    private static IEnumerable<TSource> Prepend<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource item)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        yield return item;

        foreach (var element in source)
            yield return element;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Permutations<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var list = source.ToList();

        if (list.Count > 1)
            return from s in list
                   from p in Permutations(list.Take(list.IndexOf(s)).Concat(list.Skip(list.IndexOf(s) + 1)))
                   select p.Prepend(s);

        return new[] { list };
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "acn";

        foreach (var permutation in s.Permutations())
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(permutation));
    }
}
```

### Output

```
acn
anc
can
cna
nac
nca
```